# Comparing string values of two columns in scala

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

I have two string columns, x and y, in a dataframe that i want to compare. If they are the same (case insensitive), I want to return x and if they are different, I want to concatenate x and y.
I know I can do this in SQL but i'm trying to do it in scala

```
select (case when x = y then x else concat(x + ". " + y) end) as match from test
```

in scala

```
df.select(when(col("x") == col("y"), col("x") )
        .otherwise(concat(col("x"),lit('. '), col("y")))
        .as("match"))
```

I get the following error when i test

> error: type mismatch; found   : Boolean required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use === instead of == for equality checks on scala spark.

```
  df.select(when(col("x") === col("y"), col("x") )
        .otherwise(concat(col("x"),lit('. '), col("y")))
        .as("match"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a spark question than a scala question.
You should be using `===` instead of `==`.